# How to debug TypeScript by printing the inferred variable type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Often TS fails for me because the type it infers is different from what I expect it to be. I could force typecast variables, but I'd prefer to figure out why TS isn't inferring the types correctly.

Is there a way to print the type that TS believes a variable is?

E.g.:

```
const obj = [
  { a: 'foo' },
  { b: 'bar' },
];

printTsType(obj[0].a);
```

I would expect this to be the literal `'foo'`, but I think TS just infers `string`.

Comment: typeof(obj[0].a) isn't this?

Comment: "*Is there a way to print the type that TS believes a variable is?*" no. The type system exists at compile time, not when the code is running.

Comment: "*I would expect this to be the literal `'foo'`, but I think TS just infers `string`.*" TS will indeed infer it as `string`. It finds the closest that matches and skips literals. Otherwise you'd have to use a lot more type annotations. Imagine a `let i = 0` was inferred as a literal zero, then `i++` will not work.

Comment: @VLAZ when TS is compiling, I want the compiler to dump whatever type it inferred when it hits a particular line. I guess it should be a compiler directive and not a JS function

Comment: If I have `const str = 'foo'`, it infers it as the literal `'foo'`, but I don't understand why TS treats it as a generic `string` when it's in a nested object

Comment: Your editor should be able to tell you what something is if you hover your mouse over it, for example. If you want it programmatically, then you'd need to get a hold of the intermediate representation that TS produces. This should be exposed somehow as people have wrote plugins using that information.

Comment: @LeoJiang a `const` is not a mutable binding, so it will never change. No need to expand it to `string`. But `let str = "foo"` is mutable. It will be rather useless if you couldn't assign anything else to it - it's basically a `const`. Object properties are mutable.

Comment: @LeoJiang You could force TS to infer type of `obj[0].a` to be `'foo'` by using `{a: 'foo' as const}` or `const obj = [...] as const` depending on your requirements.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko that seems like the root of that particular snippet! I'll ask a separate question about how to make a nested object const in TS.

Comment: @LeoJiang you cannot make an object a const. You can use the `as const` directive but it's not automatic - you have to add it yourself manually. If you tell us what you're trying to achieve, it would be easier to find a solution.

Comment: There's a way (sort of) for TS to report what type it infers. Just `export` all definitions you want in the file and then tell TSC to emit the declaration file

`tsc -d  app.ts`

which produces app.d.ts. Look in the file for answer.

For Angular you may need to add flag `--experimentalDecorators` to tsc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One trick to learn what is the inferred type is to pass that variable to a function that expects a different type (e.g. `never`) to generate a compiler error which will tell you "*inferred type* is not assignable to never".
TS Playground example: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=10#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBtAUDGBvGAhgFwwDkAZiCKTAL4A02eM8Jp8BATjQ5gLoBuTJnIBXMMCgBLcDEogAFMRhgApgDdVnAJTNaw%20QoSJtAoA)

Comment: Even shorter way is `let foo: never = objectWithUnknownType`

Comment: For now I prefer this to installing some ide or intellisense to use typescript.